# @model.map(&:attributes) and virtual attributes

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, virtual-attribute

How can i use @model.map(&:attributes) to make it so that virtual attributes show up in when I render @model as json

Comment: Your example doesn't tell us what `@model` is. As a singular name I'd assume it's an ActiveRecord object but then calling `#map` on it makes no sense.

Comment: .map(&:attributes) is shorthand for mapping all attributes of @model without having to manually specify them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@model.to_json(:method => ['virtual_attribute1', 'virtual_attribute2']))
```

Didn't understand the `map` call either

Comment: .map(&attributes) is short hand for mappng all the attribute of an object and your answer worked perfectly.  Thx man.